# How can I check i 2 fields of a form have the same content using a rule array of laravelcollective/html validator?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-validation

I am pretty new in **Laravel** and I have the following problem.

I have this method that handle the submit of a form:

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    Log::info('store() START');

    $data = Input::all();

    Log::info('INSERTED DATA: '.implode("|", $data));

    $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required',
        'surname' => 'required',
        'login' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'emailConfirm' => 'required|email',
        'pass' => 'required',
        'passlConfirm' => 'required',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',

    );

    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::to('/registration')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }
    else{
        // Do your stuff.
    }
}
```

As you can see it contains a **$rules** array containing the **validation rules**.

It works pretty fine but I want also perform the following 2 checks:

1. The **email** field have to contains the same text than the **emailConfirm** field.
2. The **pass** field have to contains the same text than the **passConfirm** field.

Can I implement this kind of check into the **$rules** array?

Answer (score 4):

Actually Laravel comes with the validation rule called [confirmed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-confirmed). You will need to change your fields to `email_confirmation` and `pass_confirmation` and add `confirmed` rule to `email` and `pass` fields.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @Mariusz, Laravel come up with value comparison rule as **confirmed** rule. To acheive your output you should write,

```
 $rules = array(
    'name' => 'required',
    'surname' => 'required',
    'login' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|confirmed|email',
    'pass' => 'required|confirmed',
    'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',

);
```

As you have mentioned, you are using laravelcollective/html, then you have to also add following code to generate confirmation fields

```
echo Form::email("email_confirmation",null, $attributes = []);
echo Form::password("pass_confirmation",null, $attributes = []);
```